# is there a way to launch Bing Vision from windows phone 8.1 app using WinJS/WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, qr-code, winjs

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 app using WinJS.
I need to scan a QR Code and I am thinking of launching Bing Vision lens from my app. I checked the url association is not available for camera.

Alternatively, I used File Open picker, so that I can use the camera button to launch camera, but this launch of camera doesn't provide options to switch lens.

Please help me on this..

Comment: Do you just want the system to just take the picture for you and then you will decode the QR code yourself, or do you want the system to decode the QR code for you and give you the data?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question, even if its an older one, here is a working solution of mine.

As I understand correctly you want to implentent QR code scanning capability without coding an own QR code scanner.
I have developed a free app for this purpose. QR Scanner RS

But first you must be familiar with using URI association. Documentation can be found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452691.aspx

Check also this sample:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec/

You can launch QR Scanner RS using following URI scheme: `"xyz-vida-rs:FREEvRSGBU="`

C# example, (use WinJS equivalent):

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("xyz-vida-rs:FREEvRSGBU=[URI of your App]"));
```

You need an own registered URI scheme for your app. Just replace [URI of your App] with your URI scheme.

Whats happening is pretty cool and simple.

You're launching QR Scanner RS from within your app. As soon as QR Scanner RS detects some QR code, barcode, ... and read it succesfully, it launches back your app (using your URI scheme) and transfers the QR code content to your app. You then just need to handle the result.

Hope this helps ;-)

**One important note**: QR Scanner RS will stay 100% free for this purpose!
You can send me your cantact data (eMail) using in app URI scheme request if you want to. I then can notify you about URI scheme extensions.